# How can I display a .pdf file from a non-public website folder?

Tags: php, html

I have several .pdf files in a non-public folder on a website.  The folder is named "protected" and is located in the same folder as the public_html folder.  All website pages are .php files.

The following HTML code properly displays the contents of the .txt file:

```
<form method="post" action="../protected/documents/test.txt">
  <input name="submit1" type="submit" value="Text File" />
  <br>                      
</form>
```

The following code returns a 404 error:

```
<form method="post" action="../protected/test.pdf">
  <input name="submit2" type="submit" value="PDF File" />
  <br>                      
</form>
```

Why does the .txt file display properly while the .pdf file does not?

Comment: Why use a form for this? A link would function the same. A 404 would mean the file isn't at the requested location. You doing any rewrites or anything like that?

Comment: How is the folder protected?

Comment: 1. I've never seen someone use a FORM for this, a href would do it better.  2. More than likely the pdf or the protected directory is not accessible but the protected/documents is, can you move the pdf to the documents to test?

Comment: You could do a binary dump of the pdf file from the protected folder into the browser, and adjust your headers to pdf

Comment: I don't see any "php" here.

Comment: You can't go using a text file as the action for PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried

```
<a href="./protected/test.txt" target="_blank">TXT File</a>
<a href="./protected/test.pdf" target="_blank">PDF File</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

those paths are not targetting the same folder, maybe test.pdf is in "../protected/documents/test.pdf"